# Xamarin.Forms Prism: Android dependency injection of platform-specific service

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

Im trying to inject a Android- and iOS-specific service, but on Android I get an error in `App.xaml.cs` about it not being able to resolve the parameter for `LoginService`

My `App.xaml.cs`:

```
    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MapsPage>();


        Container.RegisterInstance<ILoginService>(new LoginService(Container.Resolve<IClsDkwsService>()));
    }
```

My `MainActivity.cs`:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
    }
}

public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterInstance<IClsCryptoService>(new Cls_crypto());
        container.RegisterInstance<IClsDkwsService>(new Cls_dkws());
    }
}
```

It looks like `AndroidInitializer.RegisterTypes()` is called *after* `App.RegisterTypes()`. I would like to avoid registering `LoginService` in each platform. How do I ensure all platform-specific services are registered in `App.xaml.cs`?

Comment: Why your LoginService does not take in the constructor IClsDkwsService ? why does take the implementation of it . That is kind of violation of dependince injection , don't you think?

Comment: I want to register them as singletons. How else can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to manually create instances of these dependencies, use the features of the DI container.  You can register a type as a singleton in Unity by using

```
Container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```